# GDAL: Can Python GDAL.Translate convert a TIFF file to a JPEG or PNG Array--instead of writing to file?

Tags: python, image-processing, geospatial, gdal

I have python code to convert a `GeoTIFF` image file to a `JPEG` image file. However, I would like to do this in-memory, meaning that I would like to read the `GeoTIFF` file, convert it to JPEG, then store the converted data to an in-memory structure, like a `numpy` array ideally. Is there a way to do this?

Here is some sample code I was hoping to adapt:

```
from osgeo import gdal

scale = '-scale min_val max_val'
options_list = [
    '-ot Byte',
    '-of JPEG',
    scale
] 
options_string = " ".join(options_list)

gdal.Translate('test.jpg',
               'test.tif',
               options=options_string)
```

This code uses the `GDAL` python api, but it requires an output type referencing a file like `test.jpg` in the code above. But I don't want to specify an output file--instead I want to output the result to some sort of array.

Note that I did try this conversion without using `GDAL` too, but all of the pixel intensity ranges were getting compressed to a very small range instead of the range generated from `GDAL.Translate()`.

**RESEARCHED ANSWERS THAT DON'T APPLY**

Note that I researched some other Stack Exchange Posts on this topic, but they all will convert the `GeoTIFF` file to another file. I don't want to write a new file. I am including the link here for convenience, but key point is that existing posted questions don't match this one.

[how to convert geotiff to jpg in python or java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50207292/how-to-convert-geotiff-to-jpg-in-python-or-java)

Any ideas?

Comment: You do realize that you can't do much with a JPEG in memory except write it to a file, right? If you want to do something at a pixel level that's a whole different question.

Comment: I am coding some imagery from the original GeoTIFF format to a `TFRecords` format for machine learning. So I never actually use the PNG or JPEG files, I just need the data converted from TIFF format into a format that is formatted like PNG or JPEG. It needs to be formatted like PNG or JPEG so that I can validate that the image went into `TFRecords` properly when I decode the data.

Comment: You should have put that information in the question. You don't actually want PNG or JPEG format, you want something that can be used natively by `tf` without reading it from a file.

Comment: @MarkRansom Good point. `Tensorflow` is so ambiguous. So you can technically I can write any kind of information as a string to this `TFRecords` format. So I could even directly code the TIFF file to string and pass it to `Tensorflow`. BUT, `Tensorflow` does have some built in functions to parse JPEGs and PNGs, and I need to make sure that `Tensorflow` recognizes this as an image. I just thought some of these details might distract from the core of the question. But I definitely could have added more context to help explain the question.