# Can I input rainfall data in the form of 'geotif' as input data for a DNN model? Possibly Keras/ Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, dotnetnuke, spatial, geotiff

I am trying to apply Deep Learning for a classification problem. I have rainfall data, DEM in 'geotif' format. Do I have to convert it and then provide as an input or can the 'geotif' image directly go as an input. I am using Python and is new to the whole setup. I have installed Tensorflow and in the way to Keras. What exactly am I supposed to do hereafter?

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your geotiff files to jpg, then, you will be easily use all the pretrained models and you will get your model in less time.

For converting the geotiff to jpg, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50207292/how-to-convert-geotiff-to-jpg-in-python-or-java).

Comment: Gr8..thanks for the link. Any idea if gdal.Translate is available in Python?

Comment: Yes. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42584/how-to-call-gdal-translate-from-python-code